# Why gives Git a merge conflict, when I rebase a local branch on another local branch to exclude a commit from its history?

Tags: git

A branch `dummy` is created. The first commit on the new branch adds a file `a.py`. In the next commit the variable `a` is assigned the value `1` in the first line of `a.py`. The next four commits assign increasing values to `a`. Finally a second branch `dummy2` is created that points to the last commit. The commit history of `dummy` and `dummy2` looks like this:

[image]

Let's assume in the second commit (`a = 1`) something was done that should be included in the history of `dummy`, but excluded from the history of `dummy2`. A way to achieve this would be to rebase `dummy2` on `a=2` . The syntax to do so is:

```sh
git rebase --onto ecd5f3fe 718f88d8 dummy2
```

Git should now copy commits `a=2` to `a=5` and attach them to commit `added a file` . However, using this approach we run into a merge conflict:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in my_scripts/a.py
error: could not apply 8a2a26b... a = 2
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 8a2a26b... a = 2
```

The merge conflict UI tells us, that git is uncertain about rebasing commit `a=2` on `added a file` .

[image]

We can tell git to always [prefer our current branch](https://demisx.github.io/git/rebase/2015/07/02/git-rebase-keep-my-branch-changes.html) when doing the rebase like this:

```sh
git rebase -Xtheirs --onto ecd5f3fe 718f88d8 dummy2
```

This auto-solves the merge conflict for us and gives the wanted result

[image: ![enter image description here]

However, why is git uncertain in the first place? Why does it not know, that `a=2` is the way to go in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason Git is confused here is simple enough, but before we get there, let me address a red flag here:

> The merge conflict UI ...

Git does not *have* a merge conflict UI.<sup>1</sup>  This leads to lots of people adding different ones, each of which has a different method of presenting the conflict.  It's helpful to know that Git itself provides only two things here:

- First, Git provides *all three input files*.  We'll look at this more in a moment.  These three files are all invisible: you can't *see* any of them.  You have to have Git extract them for you.  The various UIs that people add usually do this, but, well, see "different method of presenting".
- Last, Git also provides, in your working tree, its own *best effort* at merging, marked up with conflict markers.  The default conflict marker style is called `merge` style and it shows lines from *two of the three input files*.  The other conflict marker style available is called `diff3` and it shows lines from *all three of the three input files*.  I find this style superior, though you still need to know about the three input files.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can call these two things that Git provides a UI, but ... that takes us back to [a quote attributed to Abraham Lincoln](https://timpanogos.blog/2007/05/23/lincoln-quote-sourced-calfs-tail-not-dogs-tail/).  The quote says that Lincoln asked how many legs a dog has, if you call a tail a leg.  The obvious answer is 5, to which the reply is: "ah, but calling a tail a leg doesn't make it one."  According to the link here, Lincoln *did* say this, but about a calf, not a dog.

---

#### What's really going on

The `git rebase` command works, in principle and sometimes in reality, by repeatedly invoking `git cherry-pick`.  [Git's `git-cherry-pick` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) describes cherry-pick in a sentence as:

> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one
> introduces, recording a new commit for each.

(The rebase code does one at a time, for extra control, so we can disregard the "or more" part.)  "Apply the changes ... and make a new commit" means, to me, to *copy* some existing commit.  What's missing here—but is strongly hinted-at—is that this "apply the changes" is actually a *merge* operation:

> ... See [git-merge(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) for some hints on resolving such conflicts.

A merge operation involves three commits.  So: what are the three commits here?  Well, one is obvious: we have to tell `git cherry-pick` which commit we want it to copy, as in:

```
git cherry-pick a123456
```

to copy a commit whose hash ID is `a123456`.

Now, if we look at a commit with `git show` or `git log -p`, we typically *see* the commit as a set of changes, along with some additional information like the commit's hash ID, author, and so on.  But no commit actually stores *changes;* all commits store, instead, *snapshots* plus *metadata*.  The snapshot is a *full snapshot of every file that Git knew about* at the time you, or whoever, made the commit.  The metadata is where Git keeps things like the name of the person who made the commit, and any log message they provided.

How, then, can we get a set of changes—a "what's different"—from a snapshot?  The answer is simple: we put up *two* snapshots, side-by-side, and then play a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference).  If you click on this link you'll see some side-by-side snapshots.  I hope I am not giving too much away by saying that in one pair of snapshots, one of the differences is that the cat goes from holding a spoon, to holding a lollipop.

Here, Git takes on the work of spotting the differences.  It then prints, for us to view, a list of "diff hunks", saying: *If you take the file on the left, and make these changes to it, you'll get what's in the file on the right.*

So, to turn a commit into *changes*, we need to compare the commit's snapshot with some earlier snapshot.  How do we do that?

Well, each commit doesn't *just* store a snapshot.  It also stores metadata: the author's name, for instance.  In the metadata, Git adds something that *Git* needs: the *parent commit ID.*  Every commit has a unique ID number, which we usually call a *hash ID*.  Git calls it an *object ID*.  Git used to call it a *SHA-1 hash*, but the Git folks are trying to move from SHA-1 to SHA-256.  Whatever we call it, it's a number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), that allows any Git anywhere in the universe to find the commit, as long as that Git actually *has* the commit, because that number is unique to *that one particular commit*.

If some commit whose hash ID is `C` (Commit or Child) holds the hash ID of its immediate predecessor commit—let's call that "commit `P`", for Parent—then we say that commit `C` *points to* commit `P`.  In fact, almost every commit<sup>2</sup> has a parent, or sometimes more than one parent:

```
C1 <-C2 <-C3 ... <-Cn-1 <-Cn   <--branch
```

is a simple chain of commits that we've numbered.  The branch name `branch` points to the *last* one in the chain, which points back to the next-to-last, which points back further.  Eventually we get to the very first commit, numbered `1` here instead of the proper zero<sup>3</sup> so that `n` commits count from `1` through `n` inclusive here.

---

<sup>2</sup>The only exception to this rule is a so-called *root commit:* every non-empty repository has one, because the very first commit we make in a new, empty repository is, by definition, the *first* commit, and therefore has no parent.  It's possible to put more than one root commit into a repository, but that takes a little bit of extra work.  The *first* one is free, though, because it happens naturally.  There's no reason to *want* extra root commits: they're just starting points, which makes them the end of history.  *History*, in a Git repository, is just commits.  *Earlier* history is thus earlier commits, and when you hit a / the root, there's nothing earlier.

<sup>3</sup>How to start an argument with a group of math or informatics people: ask whether to start numbering from zero.

---

#### Merging

You're asking about cherry-picking—well, about *rebasing*, but that *means* cherry-picking—but it's a good idea to start with a real merge first, because in a real merge, this all makes more sense.

When we merge, we have two branches.  The commits on these two branches might look a bit like this:

```
       o--...--I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
      /
...--B
      \
       o--...--K--L   <-- branch2
```

The newer commits are towards the right, so that `J` and `L` are the *last* commits on these two branches.  We did a `git checkout branch1` or `git switch branch1` to pick commit `J` to work on / with.

Commit `J` points back to earlier commit `I`, which points back to more commits and so on.  Commit `L`, meanwhile, points back to some earlier commit `K`, which points back to more commits.

Now we run `git merge branch2`.  That tells Git: *Look at our commit `J` and their commit `L`.  Follow their parent connections back through history.*  Git keeps doing this until it arrives at commit *B*, which is on *both branches* and therefore acts as the *merge base* commit.

These are the three input commits for the merge process.  Commit `B`, which has a snapshot, is the *merge base*.  Commit `J`, which has a snapshot, is *our* commit.  Commit `L`, which has a snapshot, is *their* commit.  Commit `B` has the special property of being on *both* branches, and also being "better" than any *earlier* commit that's also on both branches, by virtue of being the latest commit that's on both branches.

The job of `git merge` is to *combine work*.  To do that, Git has to find *changes*.  It can do that using these snapshots.

One way would be to compare `B` to the child commit on the top line, then compare that commit to the next one, and so on until we get to `I` and then `J`.  But it's shorter, faster, and easier for Git to just compare the `B` snapshot directly to the `J` snapshot.  The result of this comparison is a bunch of diff hunks: *Do this, that, and the other thing to commit `B` and you'll get the snapshot in commit `J`.*  That's how to turn `B` into *our* commit.

Similarly, comparing the snapshot in `B` to the snapshot in `L` suffices.  This produces a bunch of diff hunks: *Do X, Y, and Z to commit `B` and you'll get commit `L`.*  That's how to turn `B` into *their* commit.

To do the merge, then, Git just has to combine all these diff hunks.  If we changed some file and they didn't, that gets our changes.  If they changed some file and we didn't, that gets their changes.  If we *both* changed some file, then ... well, as long as the changes don't *overlap*, Git can make *both* changes.  Sometimes, though, the changes overlap, or touch right at the edges.  For overlaps, there's an obvious problem, and for those that touch at edges—changes that *abut*—there is sometimes an order problem, and experience has shown that automatically combining these doesn't work so well.  So that's what Git does: it *fails to combine changes* when they overlap or abut.  This is a *merge conflict*.

When there is no merge conflict, Git is able to take the file from `B`, add any *changes* we made and any *changes* they made, and use that updated / combined-changes file as the proposed file to go in the proposed *merge commit* `M`.  When there *is* a merge conflict, Git:

1. Saves all three input files, from `B`, `J`, and `L`, in Git's *index* (aka *staging area*, but here the index has been expanded so that it can hold three copies of a single file).  **The copies of files in the index are not directly visible,** but `git status` will say that this file is *unmerged*.
2. Writes, to your working tree file—the one you can see and open in your editor to change—Git's *best effort* at merging the changes for that file.  This includes the conflict markers around the conflicting changes.  As I mentioned earlier, you get all three sets of lines—including the *original* lines from `B`—if you tell Git to use `diff3` style.<sup>4</sup>  Otherwise, you get just the `ours` (`HEAD` commit, `J` here) lines and the `theirs` (commit `L`, here) lines.

If you have `git mergetool` run some actual UI tool, or pick some UI that you like and use its merge tooling, that merge tool will probably let you get at all of these: all three input files *and* Git's attempt to merge them.  But every UI is different and you will have to check any documentation for *your* UI to see how it behaves here.

In any case, if there *are* merge conflicts, Git stops in the middle of the merge, with the index / staging-area still at least partly expanded (for each of the conflicted files).  Your job is now to *clean up the mess*, i.e., resolve each conflicted merge, however you wish to do that.  To signal to Git that the *working tree* copy of the file now contains the *correct* result, you would run `git add` on that file.  This removes the three inputs and replaces what's in the index / staging-area copy—now reduced to a *single* file copy—with a copy of what's in your working tree (but turned into something ready to commit: Git stores files in a commit, to make the the snapshot, but doesn't store these *as* ordinary everyday files: that would make Git repositories hugely fat and unwieldy).

The final result of the merge is a *merge commit:*

```
       o--...--I--J
      /            \
...--B              M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
      \            /
       o--...--K--L   <-- branch2
```

Like every commit, commit `M` stores a snapshot.  Its only special-ness is that instead of *one* parent, `J`, it adds a *second* parent, `L`, to record that (a) it is in fact a merge and (b) the merge combines the work that led to `J` with the work that led to `L`.  By resolving any conflicts here, you have declared to Git that the snapshot in `M` contains the *correct* combination.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>To do this, configure `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`, e.g.:

```sh
git config --global merge.conflictStyle diff3
```

If you dislike that, configure it to `merge`, or remove the `diff3` setting since the default is already `merge`.  (There are at the moment no other styles available.)

<sup>5</sup>Be sure, then, to provide the correct combination.  If you don't resolve the conflicts, but rather just `git add` the working-tree file, you're telling Git that the *correct* resolution is to *keep everything, including the conflict markers*.

---

#### Cherry-picking

In our cherry-pick example, we might have two or more branches like this:

```
       o--o--P--C--o--...--G   <-- branch1
      /
...--B
      \
       o--...--o--H   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

This is a lot like our merge example.  But we don't want to *merge* the two *branches*.  We just want to copy the effect of commit `C`, the child.  We want Git to compare the snapshot in `P`, the parent, to the snapshot in `C`.  Whatever is *different* here, those are the changes we would like Git to add to commit `H`.

But—just to take a very simple example—suppose that between `P` and `C`, *they* changed line 10 of file `xyz.py` to fix spelling in a comment:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#
# ... big comment here ...
```

Meanwhile, in *our* commit `H`, that's **not line 10**.  Our comments are either longer or much shorter.  Let's say that the spelling error exists, but is on line 4.

If all we have is a diff hunk, we *might* be rescued here by using the context of the diff hunk.  But Git can do much better than just guessing based on context.  What if we have Git run a `git diff` that compares the snapshot in `P` to the snapshot in *our* commit `H`?

*This* diff will say: *Delete all the lines from line 3 to line 8.*  That is, what is line 10 in *their* diff—to fix the spelling error—corresponds to stuff six lines *earlier* in *our* diff, because to go from snapshot `P` to snapshot `H`, we delete six lines above this point.

This extra diff information gives Git *precisely what it needs* to apply "their" changes to "our" file.  So Git does this.  But now we go on to observe some mathematical properties about applying diffs:

- A deletion is like subtracting things.
- An addition is like adding things.
- So if we take what's in snapshot `P` and apply *our changes* to add and delete stuff, and combine that with *their changes* to add and delete stuff, we'll delete exactly the *right* stuff, and add exactly the *right* stuff, to *keep our changes* and at the same time *add their changes*.

This means we can treat the files from commit `P` as a *merge base*, and simply use the existing merge engine, just as `git merge` would do.  The only thing special about all of this is that `P`, not `B`, is the merge base—and when Git is done, the new commit should not be a *merge commit*, but instead just an ordinary commit:

```
       o--o--P--C--o--...--G   <-- branch1
      /
...--B
      \
       o--...--o--H--C'  <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

The difference between `H` and `C'`, our new commit, should be the same as the difference between `P` and `C`, except for line numbers and such—and, except for any *merge conflicts* that require resolving.

#### A concrete example: your case

In your case, you have a commit, `8a2a26b...`, that changes:

```
a = 1
```

(in its parent commit, whatever hash ID that is) to:

```
a = 2
```

You're trying to cherry-pick this atop a commit that has no `a =` line at all.

Git therefore diffs the parent of `8a2a26b...` against the current commit.  This diff says:

```
-    a = 1
```

i.e., delete the line that assigns 1 to `a` entirely.<sup>6</sup>  That's *your* change: delete that line.

Meanwhile, Git also diffs the parent of `8a2a26b...` against `8a2a26b...`.  This diff says:

```
-    a = 1
+    a = 2
```

i.e., *change* the line that assigns `1` to `a`, to a line that assigns `2` to `a`.

Git gets a conflict because it cannot combine "delete the line" with "change the line".  With a `diff3` style diff, you'll see all three lines, including the `a = 1` from the "merge base" (parent of `8a2a26b...`).

The `-X theirs` extended-option<sup>7</sup> tell Git that, in the case of a conflict, it should favor taking "their" change.  So instead of trying to delete the line entirely, Git will keep the "change assignment" line from the parent commit.  Note that in later cherry-pick operations, this will again tell Git to prefer "their change", so if we have some *other* merge conflicts that we have to solve, this could drop anything we do earlier in our rebase.  It's a bit dangerous to allow Git this much power: it works fine if there are no other conflicts, or we don't have to resolve anything by doing what Git considers a "keep ours" style change, but any time you have to resolve conflicts, always check the results, whether you do that manually (by resolving the conflict yourself) or automatedly (with a tool or an extended option or whatever).

---

<sup>6</sup>Since this is Python, it's more technically correct to say that this *binds* the value `1` to the *name* `a`.  And of course, [technically correct is the best kind of correct](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/48a9bw/why_is_technically_correct_the_best_kind_of/), hence this footnote.

<sup>7</sup>Git calls these *strategy-options*.  But `-s` sets the *strategy* and is thus the *strategy option*.  We're supposed to remember that `-s` is the strategy option, and `-X` is the strategy-option option?  Let's just call `-X` the eXtended option.

Comment: What a honor to receive such a great answer. Thanks for making the effort. A few things are still unclear to me. Firstly: "Delete all the lines from line 9 to line 8". Shouldn't this state "from line 9 to line 4"? Secondly: Isn't it safe to choose the `-X theirs` extended option when all I want to achieve with the rebase is to create a branch A (`dummy2`) whose history is a clone of another branch B (`dummy`), except that it lacks the changes made in a specific commit (or a sequence of consecutive commits) on branch A?

Comment: Thirdly: If I understood what you wrote about the cherry-pick nature of rebasing correctly the second cherry-pick (the one after the one you described in detail in the  "A concrete example: your case"-section) would merge commits `a=3` (*theirs*) and `a=2'` (*ours* (the commit resulting from the merge of the first cherry pick)) based on the parent commit `a=2` . Is that right?

Comment: Er, I meant "line 3 to line 8", no idea how 9 got in there: I wanted 6 lines gone, so that 10-6=4. Will fix. (2) Using this `-X` option is certainly safe in this particular case. I just meant that in general, it's giving Git a lot of power, so watch out. (3) yes, that's quite right.

Comment: @torek when are you going to publish a Git book with all your wonderful in-depth explanations of how Git works internally and how that maps to the UI? :)

Comment: @knittl: It was in progress for a while, then stalled for years, and if I can just get it started up again... :-)